# UIImage resize, crop and rotate with frame

Tags: iphone, resize, uiimage, rotation, crop

I'm searching for library or just code snippet to provide function like resize, crop with frame and rotate image after user pick image from image picker. Something like on this video: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Gb6xncXg1PY (0:55). Maybe someone has the same issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This one could help you relating the images. It's for iPad but this shouldn't make much differences. The principles should be the same. (icodeblog.com is really a good page, could be that there is much more relating this issue)
http://icodeblog.com/2010/10/14/working-with-uigesturerecognizers/

But there are also so much out which you can find via Google. I had a good one but I don't find it anymore.